# C++ program terminates without executing the catch block

Tags: c++, try-catch, mpi, terminate

I'm running a code in parallel using mpi 
my program terminates and displays `Assertion (unsigned long)(size) >= (unsigned long)(nb) failed terminated by signal 6`

I added to my main try and catch as the following

```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rankid;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rankid);

    try
    {
      call functions 
     }
    catch(...)
     {
        cout<<"error from "<<rankid<<endl;
        throw;
      }
     return 0;
 }
```

I'm compiling my code using `mpicxx example.C` and running it by

```
 mpirun -np 2 ./a.out
```

my code terminates without printing the phrase in the catch, is it try and catch supposed to force my program to execute what is in the catch

Comment: My black cat is having a nap and the crystal ball is in for repair - what does `call functions` do?

Comment: Signal != exception. Signals are much lower than exceptions. You need to catch them with a signal handler. Odds are pretty good that your program is too broken to live if an abort signal was raised. Don't handle it and carry on. Handle it and take the opportunity to print a diagnostic you can use to actually fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere, among your `call functions`, there is probably a usage of `assert()`.   If the assertion fails, the result is exiting the program by calling `abort()`, which (with your implementation i.e. compiler/library) generates a `SIGABRT` (value `6`) signal.

The thing is, `abort()` is not required to - and generally does not - throw a C++ exception  (since it was inherited from C, a language which knows nothing about C++ exceptions).   Similarly, raising a `SIGABRT` signal (the means your implementation uses in `abort()`) exits the program in a manner that has nothing to do with C++ exceptions.

The only things a `catch(...)` clause will catch are C++ exceptions.   It is not a catch-all (no pun intended) for intercepting any event that causes program termination.

You can possibly intercept the `SIGABRT` signal by using the `signal()` function to establish an appropriate signal handler.   In practice, it might be more fruitful to work out what is causing your `call function` to call `abort()`.  In other words, ensure the condition it is asserting is valid.   To work out how to to that, you will need to read documentation for the functions being called.